# How can I specify a path and filename for my files with meteor and collectionfs filesystem

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using CollectionFS to store files uploaded from my meteor app. I'm using the cfs-filesystem package to save my files using the local filesystem.

Right now, when I upload a file, it gets saved to ~/uploads/images-h9jWnALqSZMpAX4h4-IMG_3737.JPG

I have an existing filesystem structure that I need to work with and we need the files to be easy to traverse by hand if necessary.

Suppose I want to customize that path to be something like this ~/uploads/jaredtmartin/IMG_3737.jpg. And when a different user uploads, it goes to a new folder with his name, for example, ~/uploads/suzyq/IMG_1234.jpg. Can that be done? If not, where can I dig in to modify the code to make it happen?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I am have the same issue, and the answer below does not show how to create the directory for each user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `fileKeyMaker`, see [here](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-s3/issues/17)

```
var imageStore = new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {
  fileKeyMaker: function (fileObj) {
    // Lookup the copy
    var store = fileObj && fileObj._getInfo(name);
    // If the store and key is found return the key
    if (store && store.key) return store.key;

    // TO CUSTOMIZE, REPLACE CODE AFTER THIS POINT

    var filename = fileObj.name();
    var filenameInStore = fileObj.name({store: name});

    // If no store key found we resolve / generate a key
    return fileObj.collectionName + '-' + fileObj._id + '-' + (filenameInStore || filename);
  }
});
```

Comment: Please provide full text instead of a link, or this answer will be deleted by the community.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler solution (IMHO).

In the declaration of the storage adapter you can do something like this:

```
var photoStore = new FS.Store.FileSystem("photos", {
  transformWrite: function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
    gm(readStream, fileObj.name).resize(100,100,"^").gravity('Center').crop(100,100).quality(100).autoOrient().stream().pipe(writeStream);
  },
  beforeWrite:function (fileObj) {
    var post = Posts.findOne(fileObj.postId);
    if (post.type==='Dog') return {name:slugify(post.name)};
    else return {name:slugify(post.title)};
  },
});
```

In this example, some of the images for my were named using the name property and others using the title property. In the example above, I didn't preserve the extensions, but I think you get the idea. I removed that for clarity.  If you need that code, let me know. I have it.
Now this doesn't actually put the images in different folders, but it does allow you to name the files.